# How to filter List<T> with LINQ and Reflection

Tags: c#, linq, list, generics, reflection

i am getting properties via reflection and i was doing like this to iterate on the list.

```
private string HandleListProperty(object oldObject, object newObject, string difference, PropertyInfo prop)
{

   var oldList = prop.GetValue(oldObject, null) as IList;
   var newList = prop.GetValue(newObject, null) as IList;

   if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(List<DataModel.ScheduleDetail>))
   {
      List<DataModel.ScheduleDetail> ScheduleDetailsOld = oldList as List<DataModel.ScheduleDetail>;
      List<DataModel.ScheduleDetail> ScheduleDetailsNew = newList as List<DataModel.ScheduleDetail>;

      var groupOldSchedules = ScheduleDetailsOld
                             .GroupBy(x => x.HomeHelpID)
                             .SelectMany(s => s.DistinctBy(d => d.HomeHelpID)
                             .Select(h => new { h.HomeHelpID, h.HomeHelpName }));

      var groupNewSchedules = ScheduleDetailsNew
                             .GroupBy(x => x.HomeHelpID)
                             .SelectMany(s => s.DistinctBy(d => d.HomeHelpID)
                             .Select(h => new { h.HomeHelpID, h.HomeHelpName }));

     var AddedHomeHelp = string.Join(",", groupNewSchedules
                        .Where(x => x.HomeHelpID != null && !groupOldSchedule
                        .Any(y => y.HomeHelpID == x.HomeHelpID))
                        .Select(x => "\"<strong>" + x.HomeHelpName + "\"</strong>"));

     var RemovedHomeHelp = string.Join(",", groupOldSchedules
                          .Where(x => x.HomeHelpID != null && groupNewSchedules
                          .Any(y => y.HomeHelpID != x.HomeHelpID))
                          .Select(x => "\"<strong>"+x.HomeHelpName+"\"</strong>"));

   difference += string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(RemovedHomeHelp) ? string.Empty : "<strong>HomeHelp</strong> " + RemovedHomeHelp + " Removed<br/>";

   difference += string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(AddedHomeHelp) ? string.Empty : "<strong>HomeHelp</strong> " + AddedHomeHelp + "Added<br/>";
   }
}
```

Now i am making it generic because there will be coming different types of Lists and i don't want to put if conditions this way i want to write
generic code to handle any type of list.

I came up with this way:

```
private void HandleListProperty(object oldObject, object newObject, string difference, PropertyInfo prop)
{

   var oldList = prop.GetValue(oldObject, null) as IList;
   var newList = prop.GetValue(newObject, null) as IList;

   var ListType = prop.PropertyType; 
   var MyListInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(ListType);

   MyListInstance = oldList;            
}
```

i am able to get the items in `MyListInstance` but as the type will come at runtime i am not getting how to write linq query to filter them, any idea how to do.

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your code - it's very hard to read at the moment, with the indentation all over the place.

Comment: If i understand your problem correct i would pass a delegating function to this method to do the filtering. Your specific implementation seems to do nongeneric things, so you can't really leave it in there.

Comment: @AndreasMüller did'nt got your point can you elaborate?

Comment: First problem : I don't think all your list have an `HomeHelpId` and `HomeHelpName` property, do they ? If they don't, you'll need to pass these properties (property name), too.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus ofcourse ``DataModel.ScheduleDetail`` has these properties

Comment: But if it's generic, it can be applied to other types, no ?

Comment: you misunderstood i think, i will have Lists coming of different types two lists in every case 1 old and 1 new and i want to get differences between these two lists, i am implementing log funcationality i find diference between two lists and display it

Answer (score 1):

You want to compare lists.  As I understand it, the 2 lists you compare will always be of the same type but one time it might be 2 lists of X and another time it might be 2 lists of Y.

The LINQ Except method is great for this.  By default it compares if the items are the same exact reference but with a custom comparer, it can compare based in the ID property or anything else you want.

You need to determine how you consider 2 items to be equal and create a custom comparer that implements `IEqualityComparer<T>` like below.

```
public class CompareSchedules : IEqualityComparer<ScheduleDetail>
{

    public bool Equals(ScheduleDetail x, ScheduleDetail y)
    {
        return x.HomeHelpID == y.HomeHelpID;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(ScheduleDetail obj)
    {
        return obj.HomeHelpID;
    }
}

public static class SuperDuperListComparer
{
    public class ListCompareResults<T>
    {
        public List<T> RemovedItems { get; set; }
        public List<T> AddedItems { get; set; }
    }

    public static ListCompareResults<T> CompareLists<T>(IList<T> list1, IList<T> list2, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        var addedItems = list2.Except(list1, comparer).ToList();
        var removedItems = list1.Except(list2, comparer).ToList();
        return new ListCompareResults<T>
        {
            AddedItems = addedItems,
            RemovedItems = removedItems
        };
    }

    public static ListCompareResults<T> CompareLists<T>(IList<T> list1, IList<T> list2)
    {
        return CompareLists<T>(list1, list2, EqualityComparer<T>.Default);
    }
}
```

and here is some example code.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestListComparer()
    {
        var list1 = new List<ScheduleDetail> { 
            new ScheduleDetail { HomeHelpID = 1},
            new ScheduleDetail { HomeHelpID = 3}
        };

        var list2 = new List<ScheduleDetail> { 
            new ScheduleDetail { HomeHelpID = 1},
            new ScheduleDetail { HomeHelpID = 5}
        };


        var comparison = SuperDuperListComparer.CompareLists(list1, list2, new CompareSchedules());


    }


    public class ScheduleDetail
    {
        public int HomeHelpID { get; set; }

    }
```